# APScheduler won't schedule jobs

Tags: python, flask, apscheduler

I have two scripts

this one is to start Flask and the ASP scheduler

```html
from flask import Flask
from messaging import sendmsg
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


app = Flask(__name__)


scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()

def process_webhooks(data):
    if data['event'] == 'order.created':
        sendmsg('order created')
    else:
        print(f'recieved {data["event"]}')
        scheduled_time = datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=5)
        
        scheduler.add_job(sendmsg, 'date', run_date=scheduled_time, args=['other event'], misfire_grace_time=3600)

def sendmsg(msg):
    # Define the file path
    log_file = "file.txt"
    
    # Get the current timestamp to prepend to each message
    timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    
    # Construct the log message
    log_msg = f"{timestamp} - Sending message: {msg}\n"
    
    # Open the log file in append mode
    with open(log_file, "a") as file:
        # Append the message to the file
        file.write(log_msg)
    
    # Print the message to the console (optional)
    print(log_msg)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    scheduler.start()
    app.run(debug=True)
```

this one to simulate the sending of the webhooks:

```html
from app import process_webhooks


process_webhooks({'event': 'order.updated', 'data': {'status': {'name': 'pending'}}})
```

when I run the second script on the terminal I get:
recieved order.updated

and nothing else happens.

What I'm trying to achieve is to be able to schedule the tasks when the webhooks is received at a specific time the user picks